# Is publication an important criteria to get a post doc in microbial ecology?

Tags: microbiology

I am a researcher in microbial ecology , currently searching for post doc in European countries. I have publication less than 1 impact factor. Will this hinder my chances of getting selected . Please suggest?

Comment: Welcome! You might get a good answer (or find a similar one answered) on http://academia.stackexchange.com ; Personally, I would recommend to rephrase your question slightly to invite recommendations that will help you further (rather than getting a yes/no answer), e.g.: "Only published in low impact journals - how to maximize chance to do a PostDoc position in Europe?". You could possibly also add other information (e.g.: whether other students in your current department publish similarly).

Comment: We can also migrate the question to academia, if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is not the best community for this question, since it is not really about biology. But to give a glimpse of an answer:

- Having publications in high rated journals certainly increases your chances of getting a postdoc position.
- It also depends on the general level/rate of publications in your field: in some fields having a few publications after a PhD is normal, while in the others the first publication may appear in press years after you graduate (not counting the thesis).
- Then again, a publication in a top journal does not necessarily testify to one's abilities - e.g., if you are one among a few dozens of authors.
- Networking and personal recommendations are often as important in getting positions as having publications.